# Bootstrap error when initializing Twitter API in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, twitter

java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #2 bootstrap method when I am trying to initialise Twitter using API key and secret key in my Application class. Below is the code am using to initialise Twitter

```
   val config = TwitterConfig.Builder(this.applicationContext)
            .logger(DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))//enable logging when app is in debug mode
            .twitterAuthConfig(
                TwitterAuthConfig(
                   resources.getString(R.string.com_twitter_sdk_android_CONSUMER_KEY),
                    resources.getString(R.string.com_twitter_sdk_android_CONSUMER_SECRET)))
            //pass the created app Consumer KEY and Secret also called API Key and Secret
            .debug(true)//enable debug mode
            .build()

        //finally initialize twitter with created configs
        Twitter.initialize(config)
```

Comment: Could you add the code you are using?

Comment: @MaartenDev above is the code which am using to initialise Twitter in application class's onCreate Method

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find a solution to this problem but there are few resources out there for Twitter integration for android and of course for its debugging problems. 
So here is the solution i found myself and might help someone in future
the error is resolved when you add target version of java to 8 in your app gradle file in side android block

```
   compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility = "8"
        sourceCompatibility = "8"
    }
```